# Symmetric Algebra and Graded Symmetric Algebra of a Graded Module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, graded-algebras

Let $k$ be a commutative ring. Let $M=\oplus_iM_i$ be a $\mathbb Z$-graded $k$-module. There is the symmetry algebra of $M$, defined as

$$\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}(M):=T^{\bullet}(M)/\langle x\otimes y-y\otimes x~|~x, y\in M\rangle$$
and there is the so-called graded symmetric algebra of $M$, defined as

$$\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}(M):=T^{\bullet}(M)/\langle x\otimes y-(-1)^{|x||y|}y\otimes x~|~x, y\in M\rangle,$$

where $|x|, |y|$ are the degrees of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Both are graded algebras with grading defined the same way- the grading is inherited from the tensor algebra.

Why is the latter called graded symmetric algebra, when the first one is graded, too?

Comment: the second one has a bigrading, as in the first one you consider is actually the symmetric algebra of $M$ without grading and later the grading ammended. I understand that this is weird, but the sign in the second definition is essential to make for $M$ a dg-module the $\mathrm{Sym}(M)$ into a dg algebra. If you even consider the first one as graded module.

Comment: First, if $M$ is a $k$-module concentrated in degree $0$, then the symmetric algebra of $M$ is not graded, as each piece $\mathrm{Sym}^n(M)$ has degree $0$. Is that what you say? On the other side, if $M$ is graded, then the grading on $\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}(M)$ stems only from the $\mathbb Z$-grading of $M$ and does not take into account the pieces $\mathrm{Sym}^n(M)$. Is that what you claim? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Is there a reference where these subtleties are explained? Is this related to the Adams grading and exterior grading? I do not understand this at all and I have not found a reference on the topic.

Comment: essentially the thingy for graded modules is actually the construction for differential graded modules applied to modules with zero differential. (The sign there is important in order to enforce the Leibnitz rule).
On the other hand the first construction is the construction for an ungraded module applied to a graded module and then realized, hey, that is actually graded, lets consider it like that. Hope that makes more sense

Comment: According to Proposition $10$ on page 506 of *Bourbaki*'s Algebra $I$, the symmetric algebra in the sense of the first definition in my post is also bi-graded with $\mathrm{Sym}^{m,n}(M)=\oplus\mathrm{Sym}^{n_i}(M_{m_i})$ over all $n_i$ and $m_i$ with $\sum_in_i=n$ and $\sum_im_i=m$. So, it turns out that both symmetric algebras have exactly the same bi-grading. The Bourbaki authors do not seem to deal with the graded module $M$ as if it were ungraded.

Comment: yes,  but it is implicitly done that way, as it is one to one the same construction, however, if you want to generalize it to dg-modules, which is the natural extension/incarnation of graded modules, at least for me, you need to get that sign. Essentially it is really just if you want to be able to apply it to dg-modules or not.

Comment: I think MacLane and Eisenbud have created a big mess with their imprecise definitions of the "symmetric algebra" of a graded module. To them a graded polynomial ring $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is not commutative unless the degrees of the generators $x_i$ are zero (or even) which is absolutely false. In fact, in most cases we work with a graded polynomial algebra whose generators are assigned strictly positive odd degrees.

Comment: The only place where the topic is discussed accurately is *Bourbaki*'s Algebra $I$. They show that for a given graded module $M$ you can define two different and inequivalent algebras-the symmetric algebra of $M$, which is commutative, and the universal anticommutative algebra of $M$, which is commutative up to a sign.

Comment: I understand that one might want to hold on to the concepts of ungraded algebras, however, graded commutative algebras are a more natural extension as they allow the passage to cohomology and all properties and tensor products are compatible with it, which is why you need that twisting. It is not a mess, it has a completely different aim! there is a reason why one usually does not consider the polynomial algebra as an algebra and not a graded algebra, let alone dg. And yea bourbaki is great and properly written, however, it is also now nearly 100 years old, a lot changed!